# Angular 15: Is there a way of not propagating invalid state from form control to form group

Tags: angular

Let's say there is a structure like this:

```js
group = new FormGroup({
   control1: new FormControl(null, someValidator),
   control2: new FormControl(null, otherValidator)
})
```

I would like the `group.control1`'s invalid status to not propagate to its form group while `group.control2`'s invalid status should propagate. So, `control1` will be still be checked  to show warning but when `group.valid` is called I want the following behavior, with a declarative syntax.

```js
group.control1.valid // true
group.control2.valid // false
group.valid // false

group.control1.valid // false
group.control2.valid // true
group.valid // true
```

I could check after `group.valid` if `control1` is valid but I want to do this in a declarative way rather than imperative.

Comment: No, but you can check only if the control2 is valid or not to, e.g. disabled a submit button

Answer (score -1):

Set the **updateOn** option to **submit** to stop the invalid state from propagating until the form submitted.

Sample code is for you to understand.

```
<form [formGroup]="yourForm">
  <input [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
</form>
```

Comment: I want it to check validity, I just don't want it to propagate to the group. Your solution makes it not check validity at all.